# Reading level script sends error "IndexError: string index out of range" on certain sites

Tags: python, string, indexing, beautifulsoup, range

Complete beginner here. The following code is meant to analyze **p** tags in a website (using Python) and display the site's reading level.

```
#import both BS4 and the new URLLIB using the added .request
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#credit to AbigailB (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1798848/abigailb) 
def syllables(word):
    count = 0
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    word = word.lower().strip(".:;?!")
    if word[0] in vowels:
        count += 1
    for index in range(1,len(word)):
        if word[index] in vowels and word[index-1] not in vowels:
            count += 1
    if word.endswith('e'):
        count -= 1
    if word.endswith('le'):
        count+=1
    if count == 0:
        count += 1
    return count

#site prompt, to be replaced by active tab browser address
#site = input("Enter the website to find out its reading level:")
#my_url = "{}".format(site)

#default site for testing
my_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Austen"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#empty variables to be pushed w/ extracted, looped text
senNum = []
wordNum = []
syllNum = []

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
page_soup.findAll("p")
paragraphs = page_soup.findAll("p")

#loop through every paragraph, do magic
for para in paragraphs:
    para = para.text.strip()
    paraSen = int(len(para.split('.')) - 1)
    paraWord = int(len(para.split()))
    paraSyll = syllables(para)
    intParaSen = int(paraSen)
    intParaWord = int(paraWord)
    intParaSyll = int(paraSyll)

    #append stripped values into empty variables
    senNum.append(intParaSen)
    wordNum.append(intParaWord)
    syllNum.append(intParaSyll)

#sums of all previously empty values
sumSenNum = sum(senNum)
sumWordNum = sum(wordNum)
sumSyllNum = sum(syllNum)

#averages for Flesch–Kincaid ease
avgWordsPerSen = sumWordNum/sumSenNum
avgSyllPerWord = sumSyllNum/sumWordNum

#final parts for Flesch–Kincaid ease
calcOne = avgWordsPerSen * 0.39
calcTwo = avgSyllPerWord * 11.8
finalCalc = calcOne + calcTwo - 15.59

print(finalCalc)
```

It's heavily dependent on a chunk of code I found labeled above as **def syllables(word)** (credit found above) which displays the number of syllables in a string. It works on some sites, but when I run the code on others I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Waves\Desktop\gradeLevel.py", line 48, in <module>
    paraSyll = syllables(para)
  File "C:\Users\Waves\Desktop\gradeLevel.py", line 10, in syllables
    if word[0] in vowels:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

From what I understand, it may have something to do with [0] being the first object in an array whereas I believe the original author meant for it to imply "If there are no vowel separators..." but I'm not sure. Please feel free to chime in with any unrelated critique you may have of the code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: An empty string must be passed into the syllables function.

Comment: Print out the value of the word variable above the if statement in syllable function and have a look at the value, if there is one. If there isnt one, im guessing that the para variable that is passed into the syllable function is also empty, and then maybe your scraping isnt working correctly. Hope that helps, sorry for the essay

Comment: Thank you all for the advice, I'll check back in later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is empty text in the  `p` element

```
for para in paragraphs:
    print(para)
    # <p class="mw-empty-elt">   </p>
```

just skip that

```
for para in paragraphs:
    para = para.text.strip()
    if not para:
        continue
```

Comment: Perfect! Those pesky empty elements were the exact problem, thank you!